# Status of a recently added contact

Tags: google-hangouts

Can I see a recently added contact if she is online?  Say she has not accepted my invitation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not until she accepts your invitation. That's part of the point of that feature: to prevent strangers from merely adding you and knowing if you're online.